# scrollbar in IE is working but not in chrome

Tags: html, css

i have a table like below where the scrollbar is working in IE 11 with scroll=yes, but the same is not working in Chrome.Any suggestion or help would be appreciated . thank you.

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<body scroll="yes" scrolling="yes">
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td width="25%"><label>name </label></td>
      <td width="75%"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%"><label>last name </label></td>
      <td width="75%"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%"><label>middle name </label></td>
      <td width="75%"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%"><label> name </label></td>
      <td width="75%"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: i think you're tyring to contain the table; with a scrollbar.

Comment: You need elements going past the size of your container to display (and have the use of)  a scrollbar. Then use overflow: scroll; for your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those attributes on the body element are supported in anything other than Internet Explorer. In fact, the Mozilla Developer Network website doesn't list it as an attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body

I would recommend doing it in css instead using `overflow`, `overflow-x` or `overflow-y`

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `overflow-y:auto` to your body tag and that should work. (or `overflow-y:scroll`)

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<body scroll="yes" scrolling="yes" style='overflow-y: auto;'>
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td width="25%"><label>name </label></td>
      <td width="75%"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%"><label>last name </label></td>
      <td width="75%"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%"><label>middle name </label></td>
      <td width="75%"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%"><label> name </label></td>
      <td width="75%"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```